# UnexpectedValueException "... is not a zip archive" with composer

Tags: amazon-web-services, exception, composer-php

On AWS server, I have a testing environment and was running well but suddenly it gives me the following error while I tried to deploy the new changes (BTW, in the meantime the WIFI has changed due to HomeOffice)

```
Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
Install of mandrill/mandrill failed

[UnexpectedValueException]                                                                                                  
'/var/www/vhosts/testing4a.example.com/vendor/composer/3e7ad5f270bd79e05aa39b51b8a9cf24.zip' 
is not a zip archive.
```

So far tried:

1. I also tried with another network(WIFI) but still same issue.
2. Cleared composer cache

Comment: What command are you running? `composer install`? Have you tried deleting the `vendor` directory and running `composer install` again?

Comment: Hi @DelenaMalan Every time I run the deploy script and it creates new one.

cd /var/www && . deploy.sh testing4a
rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/testing4a.example.com
mkdir /var/www/vhosts/testing4a.example.com
git clone git@bitbucket.org:example/xxxx.git .
download composer.phar ...
php composer.phar install --no-dev
Installing dependencies from lock file
  - Installing mandrill/mandrill (1.0.55): Extracting archive
    Failed to execute (9) unzip -qq  '/var/www/vhosts/testing4a.example.com/vendor/composer/...ec4507.zip' 
and the error on the question.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all relevant information, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Solved here
**https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5982**

try

```
    composer clear-cache
```

```
    composer global update
```